# How do some files not execute when required in irb?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, irb

If I have `file.rb`:

```
puts "Hello, World"
```

then in irb type:

```
require "./file.rb"
```

the output will be `Hello, World`.

Why then, if I have a sinatra file, e.g.

```
require "sinatra"
get "/" do
    return "Hi"
end
```

and require that, there is no output?

**Clarification**

What executing the sinatra file via `ruby sinatra_app.rb` it will start a rack server, and not stop until CTRL+C is pressed. Why does it not do that when required in irb, but it does do that when it is explicitly run with `ruby sinatra_app.rb`?

Answer (score 1):

Because the script doesn't output anything. There is nothing in the script you showed that would generate any sort of output, there are no calls to `print`, `puts`, or `p`, no `write`s to any file, nothing.

The first script prints something when `require`d, because it prints something, the second prints nothing when `require`d because, well, it prints nothing. Remove the call to `puts` from the first script and it won't print anything either. Add a call to `puts` to the second script and it will print something.

Comment: But why doesn't it start the server, same as running `ruby app.rb`

Comment: Normally that script would start the server, not do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround is require sinatra before requiring file.

Root file:

```
require "sinatra"
require "/tmp/ddd.rb"
```

Required file:

```
get "/" do
    return "Hi"
end
```

I guess it's somehow related to Sinatra startup process. They put `get` method in default namespace, without namespacing it to separate module.

Comment: This isnt really an answer. I already can guess that its related to sinatras setup process, but I'm asking how specifically.